# Android : How to programmatically connect/disconnect OTG

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, usb-otg

I want to connect & disconnect USB OTG (pen drive, hard drive etc) programmatically in my android device

For USB, I'm using the following path to bind/unbind USB when connected to PC

```
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind or unbind
```

In the same way I want to do it for OTG.

Comment: OTG is normally supported by the hardware.  OTG means the device can be either a slave or a master.  For instance, imaging hooking up two tablets via USB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access on the device you can use a few methods I have found.  In the app you would need to call something like:

```
String[] commandConfigValue0 = { "su", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb1/bConfigurationValue", };
String[] commandConfigValue0 = { "su", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb1/bConfigurationValue", };   
String[] commandConfigValue1 = { "su", "-c", "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb1/bConfigurationValue", };
String[] commandAuthorized0 = { "su", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb1/authorized", };
String[] commandAuthorized1 = { "su", "-c", "echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb1/authorized", };
Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAuthorized0);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        Log.d("MainActivity", "From unbind: " + in.toString());

        // I don't think "rebinding" works here but if you listen for the usb disconnect you can then call this second runtime command to bind the internal usbhub
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandAuthorized1);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        Log.d("MainActivity", "From bind: " + in.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have looked at some newer devices that I own that are not rooted that also have /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb2 and there may be devices with /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/usb3.  So you may have to run through several calls depending on the devices you are wanting your app to run on.

If you are looking to do it without root access.  I am still trying to find that solution as well!

Good Luck!