# How to open OTG connection Settings

Tags: java, android

I am working with usb device connection, in some devices like **Oppo F1s** OTG connection is disabled from settings.
Check below screen shot as reference

[image]

I want to know:
1) How to check OTG connection enabled or not
2) how to open OTG connection setting page using intent

Comment: I don't think it is part of Android SDK, looks more like customization of OPPO firmware.

Comment: this behavior is provided by many device providers like oppo,vivo,xiomi so in market there are many devices having this settings even i dont find developer community for those providers. i posted here so if any buddy has out of box solution

Comment: @AMD take a look at [How to check MIUI autostart permission programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49167712/7034327), maybe you can modify the `ComponentName` value to achive what you want

Comment: This might not be possible. If I understood correctly the activity class name is `com.android.settings.SubSettings`, but the code `val intent = Intent(); intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.SubSettings")); startActivity(intent)` does not work because the settings app does not export the activity.

Comment: See also: [linux kernel - Android : How to programmatically connect/disconnect OTG - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280075/android-how-to-programmatically-connect-disconnect-otg)

Comment: It's also possible to do something similar to the app "Automate" -- enable accessibility of itself (with the user confirm some stuff once), backup the old  input method, set input method to "automate keyboard", open settings, use the accessibility features and the keyboard inputs to navigate and turn it on. The user will see some flash on the screen, though.

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to check OTG connection is enabled or not**

Android's internal setting database contains this information. The variable used to store the value is different from phone to phone. This option is available in OPPO, REALME, ONEPLUS, and VIVO. For most of the phones, you can use the below code to check whether it is enabled or not

```
 public boolean iSOTGConnectionEnabled()
{
    try {
        //all latest version
        String value = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(),"persist.sys.oplus.otg_support");
        if(value==null)
        {
            //old oppo,realme
            value = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(),"sys.oppo.otg_support");
            if(value==null)
            {
                //old oneplus phone
                value = Settings.Global.getString(getContentResolver(),"persist.sys.oem.otg_support");
            }
        }
        if(value!=null)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(value) == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
    return true;
}
```

To identify this variable name, you can use any 'setting database editor' app from play store and search for 'otg'

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if you are still interested, but I had a similar problem. Unfortunately I only found a workarround. In my case the NFC-Switch is on the same page as the OTG-Switch. So I started an Intent to open the specific Settings-page:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS); 
startActivity(i);
```

Maybe there is something like this possible for your case, too :)