# How to enable USB OTG in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, usb, settings, android-settings, usb-otg

Many android phones doesn't detect usb through OTG by default ( onePlus, oppo) it has to be enabled from settings.
Is there anyway we can enable it programmatically or the least we can directly take them to OTG settings?
Also how can we check it is enabled or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - How to open OTG connection Settings - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054349/how-to-open-otg-connection-settings)

Comment: Maybe my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68666169/13043600) can help you.